# Rewrite Rules returning wrong data

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, query, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type called `product`. It is categorized with the two taxonomies `product_category` (which is superior) and `product_group`.

I want the permalinks for single products to appear like:
`products/%product_category%/%product_group%/%postname/`
and for the "archives", in fact an overview of the products in a product category like:
`products/%product_category%/`.

This is my approach:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules');
function rewrite_rules($rules)
    {
        $newRules  = array();
        $newRules['products/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$']  = 'index.php?product_category=$matches[1]&product_group=$matches[2]&product=$matches[3]';
        $newRules['products/(.+)/(.+)/?$']       = 'index.php?product_category=$matches[1]&product_group=$matches[2]';
        $newRules['products/(.+)/?$']            = 'index.php?product_category=$matches[1]';

        return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
    }
```

Two Problems seem to appear now:

## 1. Archives (solved):

No matter which of my product categories' slugs I insert into the permalink, the query will get the posts of all categories. Why?

## 2. Single Post/Product:

This works "too good": Even if a wrong category is in the permalink, the correct post is returned. I want WordPress to redirect these wrong permalinks to the correct ones.

Any ideas?

---

### EDIT:

I solved the archive problem. I simply forgot to evaluate my query correctly. My function in `taxonomy-product_category` now at first gets the terms for `product_group` and for each term it gets all posts that belong to the current product group and to the current product category. If there are now posts, the loop is continued.

```
<?php $terms = get_terms( 'product_group', 'hide_empty=0' ); ?>
<?php foreach ($terms as $child) { ?>

    <?php
             $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'product',
                        'status'    => 'publish',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                                            array(
                                                'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
                                                'field' => 'slug',
                                                'terms' => get_query_var('product_category')
                                                ),
                                            array(
                                                'taxonomy' => 'product_group',
                                                'field' => 'term_id',
                                                'terms' => $child->term_id
                                                )
                                            )
                        );
             $current_issue_posts = get_posts($args);
             if(is_wp_error($current_issue_posts) || count($current_issue_posts)<1){
                continue; //will terminate the loop if posts found
             }
 
 /* Do stuff / output the term */

}
?>
```

Still I got that redirect problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick little search on what you are trying to do and maybe this will help you out some and how the rewrite is grabbing the querystrings.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307352/wordpress-custom-url-rewrites

Comment: Welcome to SE. If the link is relevant, we prefer that you actually put the post content into your answer (with a reference link). You never know if the linked answer might change in the future making your answer invalid :)

Comment: it was an evaluation error, see my updated question. thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks Dan for that information. Will definitely do that in the future as we know that data does tend go to la la land sometimes. -smile-. And Luke, glad you figured it out. :-)